Do I need to feed the entropy pool for /dev/random and /dev/urandom?
I'm working on an update of quite old kernel to just a bit newer and I've noticed that my /proc/sys/kernel/random is now quite different, e.g. entropy_pool (entropy_avail) value changed from 4096 to 256. I did some digging and found out my kernel update contains many of the drivers/char/random.c changes. After the update random.c claims to be cryptographically secure pseudorandom data.
In the older kernel I used rng-tools to feed the entropy and since my /dev/hwrng was disabled- I used jitter as an entropy source.
Before the update - initializing rngd took around 8 seconds when it occupied both CPUs at 100%. It was acceptable.
After  the update - it takes ~120 seconds which is not acceptable.
That made me thinking- is that possible not to feed the entropy for /dev/random at all?
I tried to learn more about this but reading all the available documentation, reddit threads, comments and posts online only got me confused.
I'm thinking about just enabling CONFIG_RANDOM_TRUST_CPU and disabling rngd but I'm worried that directly after boot the entropy_pool will not be good enough/random enough.
Main question:
Is that acceptable and safe to get rid of rngd-tools and not feed the entropy using rngd?
